# How to use pageinit for multiple data-role=page in one html file

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, page-init

I have multiple pages in my one html file.
I trying to implement the pageinit event handler on the second data-role="page".
So I declared pageinit inside it's specific data-role="page".

```
 <div data-role="page"  id="foo3" data-dom-cache="false">
<script>
    $(document).on('pageinit','#foo3' , function(){ 
    abcsong_file_path = '/android_asset/www/audio/abcsong.mp3';


        my_abc = new Media(abcsong_file_path);

        my_abc.play();
        var i =0;
        var time;
        function my_loop(){
        setTimeout(function (){


            var my_alphabets = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
            $('#content_loop2').append('<img src="img/alphabets/'+my_alphabets[i]+'.png" />');
            i++;
            time = 700;

                if(i<26)
                {
                    my_loop();
                }

            }, time)
        }
        my_loop();
    });
</script>
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">

        </div>
        <div data-role="content" >

            <div id="content_loop2"  data-inset="true">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" >

        </div>
    </div>
```

What I expected was that it would initialize everytime I visit this page. But it runs correctly only the first time I open it. Every other time it just show the output of previously executed code.

Please help me how to go about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Pageinit](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageinit/)** should run only once, it was made to be just like document ready.

If you want your code to run every time page is visited then use **[pageshow](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageshow/)** or **[pagebeforeshow](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforeshow/)**.

Read more about it **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**.

Comment: $(document).on('pageshow', function()
is firing before deviceready function of phonegap :(

Answer (score 0):

Pageinit *should* fire only once, according to the docs, but at least in previous versions that was not the actual truth.

I am currently using jQM 1.3.2 and no longer experiencing this problem on Android or in desktop browser. Pay attention to it though, especially if you are also using Phonegap.

[Document pageinit fires more than once on iOS (jQueryMobile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436315/document-pageinit-fires-more-than-once-on-ios-jquerymobile)