# Phonegap Cordova does not fire JQM pageinit

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, page-init

I have made lots of research on this topic but I did not find an appropriate answer.
My problem is that when I use Cordova/Phonegap with JQM, the `$(document).ready` is fired but not the `$(document).on('pageinit')` which is recommanded to use with JQM.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>    
    var deviceReadyDeferred = $.Deferred();
    var jqmReadyDeferred = $.Deferred();
    document.addEventListener("deviceReady", deviceReady, false);
    function deviceReady() {
        deviceReadyDeferred.resolve();
}
$(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
    jqmReadyDeferred.resolve();
});
$.when(deviceReadyDeferred, jqmReadyDeferred).then(doWhenBothFrameworksLoaded);
function doWhenBothFrameworksLoaded() {
    console.log('device ready');    
    $(document).on("pageinit",function(){   
        console.log("document pageinit fired");
    }
}
</script> 
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/buttonset.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This page is hosted on a remote server. In this case, device ready appears in the console but not document pageinit fired. If I replace `$(document).on("pageinit",function(){` by `$(document).ready(function(){`, both logs appear but I dislike this solution.

Could you please tell me where I got wrong ?

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this sequence of code in script tag.

/* Initialization of PhoneGap and jQM */

var deviceReadyDeferred = $.Deferred();
var jqmReadyDeferred = $.Deferred();


//initialize PhoneGap
document.addEventListener("deviceReady", deviceReady, false);
function deviceReady() {

}

//initialize jQM
$(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
  //hack to fix android page transition flicking issue
  if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Android") != -1){
      $.extend(  $.mobile , {
          defaultPageTransition: 'none'
      });   
    } 

  setCustomThemeAndOptions();

  jqmReadyDeferred.resolve();
});


//When both PhoneGap and jQM are ready, initialize language setting
$.when(deviceReadyDeferred, jqmReadyDeferred).then(function(){  
  deviceDeferred = true;
});
```

Comment: I forgot to explain that I use the multi-page paradigm thanks to data-role=page. Then, your code makes all the pages appear directly. I found in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693035/how-to-use-pageinit-for-multiple-data-role-page-in-one-html-file that I can put the $(document).on('pageinit') right after the <div data-role=page>. This actually works but some functions that are common to several pages still are undefined (e.g. swipe between pages with turnPage and turnPageBack functions).

Comment: Was it intended to remove deviceReadyDeferred.resolve(); in the deviceReady function? I've also tried to use .delegate method instead of .on without succcess